# Is vanilla extract haram?

Tags: halal-haram

> "That which intoxicates in large quantities is prohibited in small quantities." (Abu Dawud, Tirmidhi, Ibn Majah, and others, with a sound chain of narrators)

Does that mean vanilla extract is Haram? Because vanilla extract has vodka(or some other type of alcohol) in it. As well as, most soy sauces have 50% or more alcohol in it. Does that make soy sauce Haram as well?

Lastly, is this hadith sahih? I asked my sister if it is and she got offended (don't know why, probably b/c that would mean she would no longer be able to consume a large variety of ice creams)...

Comment: Please consider using a meaningful question title!

Answer (score 1):

السَّلامُ عليكم ورحمةالله وبركاته

I was surprised to hear this but a little research shows it to be true. Apparently it can have as much as 35% alcohol. So it is haraam. I checked with an Alim who confirms this.